# In Scala; should I use the App trait?

Tags: scala, program-entry-point, traits

I've just started learning Scala and many of the tutorials that I'm following are using a combination of different representations for a `main` method. Aside from the familiar main method; there's also the use of traits `App` or `Application`.
It appears that `Application` has been deprecated and is not recommended, but I can't find any information that explains much beyond this about each of these ways to define an entry point.

So, I'm wondering if someone could explain to me:

- How do the traits `App` and `Application` work?
- Why is the trait `Application` no longer recommended and what does the `App` trait do that is different?
- Where should I use the traditional main method and when should I use `App` to start my program? What's the difference between the two approaches?

Comment: I'd seen that SO thread, but the post about `Application` is new and interesting, thanks.
I presume that `App` inherits the same caveats as `Application`, since it's also implementing a constructor? So, what's the difference between them?

Comment: Note that the `Application` trait doesn't exist anymore in the current version of Scala, version 2.11.

Comment: In the case of Apache Spark jobs, documentation states "that applications should define a main() method instead of extending scala.App. Subclasses of scala.App may not work correctly."

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The problem with the [`Application`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.Application) trait is actually described in its documentation:

> (1) Threaded code that references the object will block until static initialization is complete. However, because the entire execution of an object extending Application takes place during static initialization, concurrent code will always deadlock if it must synchronize with the enclosing object.

This is a tricky one. If you extend the `Application` trait, you are basically creating a Java class:

```
class MyApplication implements Application {
  static {
    // All code goes in here
  }
}
```

The JVM runs the above class initializer implicitly synchronized on the `MyApplication` class. This way, it is assured that no instance of `MyApplication` is created before its class is initialized. If you spawn a thread from your application that again needs to access an instance of `MyApplication`, your application would dead lock as the class initialization is only complete after the entire program has executed. This implies a paradox as no instance can be created as long as your program is running.

> (2) As described above, there is no way to obtain the command-line arguments because all code in body of an object extending Application is run as part of the static initialization which occurs before Application's main method even begins execution.

A class initializer does not take any arguments. Also, it is run first, before any values could be handed to the class as the class initializer needs to be executed before you could even assign a static field value. Thus, the `args` that you normally receive on a `main` method are lost.

> (3) Static initializers are run only once during program execution, and JVM authors usually assume their execution to be relatively short. Therefore, certain JVM configurations may become confused, or simply fail to optimize or JIT the code in the body of an object extending Application. This can lead to a significant performance degradation.

The JVM optimizes code that is run frequently. This way, it makes sure that no run time is wasted on methods that are not really a performance bottle neck. However, it safely assumes that `static` methods are only executed once as they cannot be invoked manually. Thus, it will not optimize the code that is run from a class initializer which is however your application's `main` method code if you are using the `Application` trait.

The [`App`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.App) trait fixes all this by extending [`DelayedInit`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.DelayedInit). This trait is explicitly known to the Scala compiler such that initialization code is not run from a class initializer but from another method. Note the *for name* reference that is haded to the trait's only method:

```
trait Helper extends DelayedInit {
  def delayedInit(body: => Unit) = {
    println("dummy text, printed before initialization of C")
    body
  }
}
```

When implementing `DelayedInit`, the Scala compiler wraps any initialization code of its implementing class or object into a *for name* function which is then passed to the `delayedInit` method. No initialization code is executed directly. This way, you can also run code before an initializer is run what allows Scala for example to print an application's runtime metrics to the console which is wrapped around the program's entry point and exit. However, there are [some caveats of this approach](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4330?jql=labels%20%3D%20delayedinit%20AND%20resolution%20%3D%20unresolved) and using `DelayedInit` is therefore deprecated. You should really only rely on the `App` trait which solves the problems that are imposed by the `Application` trait. You should not implement `DelayedInit` directly.

You can still define a `main` method if you want to, as long as you define it in an `object`. This is mostly a matter of style:

```
object HelloWorld {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println("Hello, world!")
  }
}
```

Comment: What problems with the `main` method are you talking about?
In what situations should I use `App` instead of `main`?

Comment: There is no problem with defining a `main` method compared to defining a Java main method as it is invoked by the Java virtual machine after initializing the class. The `App` trait is a short cut. Other than a class initializer, a `main` method can be optimized as its code can be subject to on-stack-replacement.

Comment: @mickliddy The last sentence was unintended: I meant `Application`, not `main`.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense now.
Using `App` would also allow the code to be optimized in the same manner as `main` due to `delayedInit`, wouldn't it?