# Running Scala script with statement outside object

Tags: scala

The contents of `myfile.scala` are as follows :

```
//  println("print this line")

object myObj  {
        def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
                println("Hello, world!")
        }
}
```

If I run : `scala myfile.scala`, it prints :  `Hello, world`

If I uncomment the first println stmt, and run : `scala myfile.scala`,
it only prints : `print this line` ,
and does not print hello-world stmt.

Why is this so? I find it very confusing. I tried to search the archives, but could not find any answers.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with oo or functional programming

Comment: It's a fair question but the title is completely unrelated.

Comment: An easy way to accomplish this is to have myObj extend App. This will essentially treat the entire contents of the object as `main`.

Comment: You may reference the following questions to start an App. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24437423/in-scala-should-i-use-the-app-trait and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11667630/difference-between-using-app-trait-and-main-method-in-scala

Comment: Fair question, nothing in it to invite -1

Answer (score 4):

When the scala command sees a top level statement (not in a class or object) in the file, it runs the file as a script, starting at the first line and moving down.  You main method never gets called because you never call it, just define it.  When your file doesn't contain any top level statements but it does contain a main object, it will run the main method as the entry point to the program.