# Unable to run a Scala class in Intellij 15

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I am very new to Scala. I am using IntelliJ IDE to run a very simple program in Scala(2.11.7). 
My program goes like

```
class Rational(n:Int,d:Int) {
  val oneHalf = new Rational(1,2)
}
```

I am trying to run it as a Class rather than a object. How could I Run this class in IntelliJ?

Thanks

Comment: have you install scala plugin?

Comment: This class might cause problems - `oneHalf` is initialized when the constructor is called, but it calls the next constructor, and so on..

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥıλɐɯ Yes, I have installed a Scala plugin

Comment: @Clashsoft : This is an example I took out of the book "Programming in Scala". So I am assuming it does not call the constructor recursively

Comment: Mind you tell which page of the book? I agree with @Clashsoft that this is recursively called and you will run into issues.

Comment: I was to write this, which book and page will help to understand what you are asking for.

Comment: Its in page 131 of the book "Programming in Scala" - Martin Odersky, the solution provided by @maytham-ɯɐɥıλɐɯ helped in figuring out the solution I wanted. 
I think I was wrong about mentioning that "it does not call the constructor recursively"

Comment: @avikkal: That's not the code that the book has. I tells you to create the class `class Rational(n: Int, d: Int) {
println("Created "+ n +"/"+ d)
}` and then create a new object of that class in the REPL

Comment: BTW welcome to SO. You got my welcome voteup

Comment: @Falmarri : That's right, it tells to create the class Rational, and I was trying to Run it in IntelliJ hoping I could print these

val oneHalf = new Rational(1, 2)
val twoThirds = new Rational(2, 3)
(oneHalf / 7) + (1 twoThirds)

but I wasn't able to Run it in IntelliJ, I had to create an object as mentioned by maytham-ɯɐɥıλɐɯ to get that program running. 
Is there an another way to Run it?

Comment: If you like to work in intelliJ as alternative for REPL, just create Scala worksheet

Answer (score 4):

As @Clashsoft says you can not initialize the class like this. You can do some thing simple like this for testing:

```
class Rational(n: Int, d: Int) {
  def oneHalf: Int =
    n * d
}

object MyProgram {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val rational = new Rational(1, 2)
    println(rational.oneHalf)

  }
}
```

It is also possible to use `App` trait (`extends App`) then you do not need to have main method:

```
object MyProgram extends App {
  val rational = new Rational(1, 2)
  println(rational.oneHalf)
}
```

All depends on how you want to implement your solution at the end. Regarding different between main and `App` trait please [read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11667630/difference-between-using-app-trait-and-main-method-in-scala).

Thx to @tzachzohar for following addition:

In Scala, just like in Java, only a static `main` method (with appropriate argument and return types) can serve as a program's entry point. For convenience, IntelliJ IDEA provides a [Scala Worksheet](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-scala-worksheet.html) as a way to easily test your code, but that's no magic either - it's a just nice wrapper - behind the scenes, a worksheet has its own `main` method calling your code.