# What is the best way to write a main in scala?

Tags: scala, function, methods, program-entry-point

Since I have started to learn this language I've noticed that there are several ways to write a main method in order to run your code. What is the most used and best one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between using App trait and main method in scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11667630/difference-between-using-app-trait-and-main-method-in-scala)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
object SO extends App {
    //Your main method's code goes here, since we have extended App
}
```

or

```
object SO {
  // here goes the main
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {}
}
```

Personally I prefer the second one, as it distinguishes the main method more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

As per your question, in general to run code as executable are used :

With mixing App trait

```
object RunCode extends App {
   println("Execute here")
}
```

or concrete `main` method inside object

```
object RunCode {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        println("Execute here");
    }
}
```

The App trait is a convenient way of creating an executable Scala program. The difference to the main method alternative is that the App trait uses the delayed initialization feature.