# Scala: Spark exception when project includes Akka

Tags: scala, apache-spark, akka

I have a project that uses spark, and I want to use Akka in it. The project worked fine before, but when I added this to `build.sbt`:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.5.3"
```

And try to run the project, I get this error:

> [error] (run-main-0) org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task serialization failed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Function0 
>   [error] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Function0 
>   [error]     at sbt.classpath.ClasspathFilter.loadClass(ClassLoaders.scala:63) 
>   [error]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>   [error]     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>   [error]     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
>   [error]     at com.twitter.chill.KryoBase$$anonfun$1.apply(KryoBase.scala:41)
>   [error]     at com.twitter.chill.KryoBase$$anonfun$1.apply(KryoBase.scala:41)
>   [error]     at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
>   [error]     at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
>   [error]     at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach(Range.scala:160)
>   [error]     at 
> scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
>   [error]     at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
>   [error]     at com.twitter.chill.KryoBase.(KryoBase.scala:41)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With such build.sbt

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.11"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.5.3"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.2.0"
```

both [HelloWorld](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/simple-scala-akka-actor-examples-hello-world-actors) in Akka and [WordCount](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46013558/5249621) in Spark work fine.
Akka can work with 2.10-2.12, but Spark with 2.10-2.11. It's hard to say more without code samples and build.sbt.